# Excel formula to check for text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have this formula:

```
=IF(AD491="In progress" OR AD491="Reopened"(ROUND($BW$1-AI491,0),($BW$1-BB491+1))
```

It's checking if cell AD491 contains the words "In Progress" or "Reopened".

Excel is not allowing this formula.

I tried to do the following:

```
=IF(AD491="In progress") OR (AD491="Reopened")(ROUND($BW$1-AI491,0),($BW$1-BB491+1))

=IF(AD491={"In progress","Reopened"},(ROUND($BW$1-AI491,0),($BW$1-BB491+1))
```

But I'm still getting the Excel error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John

You have the syntax for OR wrong and you are missing commas.

```
=IF(OR(AD491="In progress",AD491="Reopened") , ROUND($BW$1-AI491,0), $BW$1-BB491+1)
```